# Double 2d array in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, square

I am trying to recreate the attached array in numpy two different ways: using operator broadcasting and for loops. For some reason I am struggling with both ways to recreate the array, any ideas?

[image: Array]

I have tried iterating with a list and other just operator (np.square()), but the 2D is tricking me up. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: With a for loop: try to write each value as a simple function of the coordinates (i,j).

Comment: What's the logic here?  Don't expect us to deduce it.  State the obvious!

Comment: z=np.arange(1,7); z*z[::-1,None]

Answer (score 0):

With a for loop:

```
import numpy

array = numpy.zeros((6,6), dtype=int)
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
        array[i,j] = (6-i)*(j+1)
```